# Parsing an HTTP POST request

Tags: java, sockets, http, inputstream

### THE GOAL

I'm trying to parse an HTTP POST request in order to retrieve the file sent with an HTML form.

This is the form:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileControl" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

### HOW

As a POST request is something similar to this:

```
POST <URL> HTTP/1.1
<HEADERS>
[BLANK LINE]
---------<BOUNDARY>
<HEADERS>
[BLANK LINE]
<file content>
-----------<BOUNDARY>
```

I think it's relevant to parse what I receive on my socket.

**First**, I read until the beginning of the file with

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
in.readLine();
```

**Then**, to save the file, this what I'm trying to do:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/test"));

while ((read = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    outputStream.flush();
}
```

### THE PROBLEM

The problem is that I'm not reading through my BufferedReader anymore, and I don't get anything in `read = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(bytes)`

### THE QUESTION

How should I save the file send over POST request? I don't want to use any webserver, nor any library/framework, only pure Java.
If something isn't clear, I'll edit this post.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're not setting up the client socket correctly, but there are a lot of places this can go wrong. If you don't want to use a library, you can at least review existing libraries to see prior art.

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Don't want a full web server, just to parse an HTTP request. Any library that can do this (in isolation without the need to start a socket server and...).

Comment: I ended up building my own parser

Answer (score 0):

```
public HttpRequest init_request(String request_str) {
    try {
        SessionInputBufferImpl sessionInputBuffer = new SessionInputBufferImpl(new HttpTransportMetricsImpl(), 2048);
        sessionInputBuffer.bind(new ByteArrayInputStream(request_str.getBytes(Consts.ASCII)));
        DefaultHttpRequestParser requestParser = new DefaultHttpRequestParser(sessionInputBuffer);
        HttpRequest request = requestParser.parse();

        // Solve post request entity bug (always returns null)
        if(request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest){
            HttpEntityEnclosingRequest ereq = (HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request;

            ContentLengthStrategy contentLengthStrategy = StrictContentLengthStrategy.INSTANCE;
            long len = contentLengthStrategy.determineLength(request);
            InputStream contentStream = null;
            if (len == ContentLengthStrategy.CHUNKED) {
                contentStream = new ChunkedInputStream(sessionInputBuffer);
            } else if (len == ContentLengthStrategy.IDENTITY) {
                contentStream = new IdentityInputStream(sessionInputBuffer);
            } else {
                contentStream = new ContentLengthInputStream(sessionInputBuffer, len);
            }
            BasicHttpEntity ent = new BasicHttpEntity();
            ent.setContent(contentStream);
            ereq.setEntity(ent);
        }

        return request;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        SLogger.error("Unable to parse request", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Apaches httpcomponets/httpclient library to generate and send the post request. Anything else is far to much work for no gain.

See https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Comment: I don't want to send a POST request, but to parse a request that I receive in a socket.